# Trying to concatenate array of c-strings with delimiter

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char const *strings[10] = {"dhh", "aci", "cdh"};
    join_def(strings, 'l');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


// part 1 read lines
void join_def(char const **strings, char delim) {
    char *t = new char[100];
    //int length = 0;
    t[0] = '\0';
    int x = sizeof(strings);
    std::cout << delim << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        int size = 0;
        while(strings[i][size]!='\0'){
            size++;
            std::cout << strings[i][size] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I have spent hours now I just can't get to concatenate it
For this task, I cannot use cstring or anything other than iostream so please don't suggest.

The output needs to be a c-string = "dhhlacilcdh"

Comment: The `sizeof(strings)` will just be a compile-time constant that is the number of bytes required to store a *pointer*. You can't get the number of elements in an array passed as an argument like that.

Comment: To get the length of `strings` either insert a `nullptr` as last element or pass the length as paramter to `join_def`.

Comment: the while loop will give you Segmentation fault [look](https://onlinegdb.com/r1_xUHJAU)

Comment: I have moved the std::cout line in while loop to before size but I still get segmentation fault, antyhing I can do to fix it?

Comment: can you add to the question of how the output of the data should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot determine the number of elements in an array passed to a function, as that array will decay to a simple pointer. So, your `sizeof(strings)` expression will evaluate (at *compile* time) to the (fixed) size, in bytes, of a pointer. For the function to be 'aware' of how many elements there are in an array, it needs to be explicitly told (by way of an extra argument).

Second, you have your `i`' and `size` indexes the wrong way round in the `std::cout << strings[i][size] << std::endl;` line and, further, you increment `size` *before* printing the relevant character, whereas it should be incremented *after* you've printed it.

The code below also does the actual concatenation of the strings, and the modified `join_def` function now returns a pointer to that result (which must be freed when you're finished with it);

```cpp
#include <iostream>

char* join_def(char const** strings, char delim, int x)
{
    char* t = new char[100];
    int length = 0;
    t[0] = '\0';
    //int x = sizeof(strings);
    std::cout << delim << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        int size = 0;
        while (strings[i][size] != '\0') {
            std::cout << strings[i][size] << std::endl;
            t[length++] = strings[i][size]; // Append this character
            size++;
        }
        t[length++] = delim; // Append delimiter
    }
    t[length] = '\0'; // Append nul-terminator
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    char const* strings[10] = { "dhh", "aci", "cdh" };
    char* result = join_def(strings, 'l', 3);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, also, that I have moved the `join_def` function code to before the `main` (which calls it). If you don't do this, then will at least have to provide a (forward) declaration of that function before main (just a `char* join_def(char const** strings, char delim, int x);` on its own will do).

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Hey, I need it to be dynamic so I cannot add a third variable to join_def. Also I need to concatenate them and return the resulting string

Comment: @Jaykch See my latest edit: I have added the code to do the concatenation and return the result. Now, when you say "I need it to be dynamic" what do you mean? How do you expect the function to know how many input strings there are? You must either tell it, or add a 'signal' (possibly empty) string at the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much man, but I need to do it without the third argument in joindef

Comment: To remove the last `delim` character, simply replave it with the null terminator (rather than appending that), using `t[--length] = '\0';` (notice the `--`) near the end of the code.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, but is there a way to write our own strlen function or something to replace the third input in join_def?

Comment: OK, maybe I could post a whole new code block, but that would make life too easy for you.  Instead, remove the third argument, and change the `for` loop to stop when an empty string is found: `for (int i = 0; strings[i][0]; i++) {`. **But note:** you will now need to *explicitly* add an empty string at the end of your array (in main), like this: `char const* strings[10] = {"dhh", "aci", "cdh", ""};`.

Comment: Yes, I got it working, thank you so much. But why do we add an empty sting at the end and is there no way to avoid it?

Comment: If you don't add that empty string, the uninitialzed members will be null *pointers* rather than empty strings. Try it and see - the program will almost certainly crash.

Comment: Yep I tried, I have to say, c++ is a very difficult language, something that is a one liner in javascript, its hard to comprehend has taken me 3 hours with help from others to do in c++

Comment: @Jaykch I don't disagree that c++ can be hard, but you are making things *much* harder because of your constraints (which seem artificial to me). e.g. [this](https://www.godbolt.org/z/V4PSBM) seems to solve the problem. Any language can be hard if you add arbitrary constraints such as not using all available features of the language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but maybe this helps?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// part 1 read lines
void join_def(char const **strings, char delim)
{
    char *t = new char[100];
    //int length = 0;
    t[0] = '\0';

    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; strings[i] != nullptr; i++)
        x += sizeof(strings[i]) - 1;
    
    std::cout << delim << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; strings[i] != nullptr; i++)
    {
        int size = 0;
        while (strings[i][size] != '\0')
        {
            size++;
            std::cout << strings[i][size] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char const *strings[] = {"dhh", "aci", "cdh", nullptr};
    join_def(strings, 'l');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful but how do I get the length of each cstring inside array and concatenate them? basically my end result should be a cstring that is "dhhlacilcdhl"

Comment: `x += sizeof(strings[i]) - 1;` you made the same mistake there. But you don't even use `x` afterwards, so this probably shouldn't be there?

Comment: My bad. I also kept the `x` there as it was in the code provided by @Jaykch and I wasn't sure what he wanted to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for?
look that I remove all the `std::endl` because it like `'\n'`
also i moved your `size++` after the `std::cout`

```
#include <iostream>


// part 1 read lines
void join_def(char const **strings, char delim,int length) {
    char *t = new char[100];
    //int length = 0;
    t[0] = '\0';
    int x = length;
   

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        int size = 0;
        while(strings[i][size]!='\0'){
            std::cout << strings[i][size]; //<--print befure increment size
            size++;
        }
         std::cout << delim;
    }
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char const *strings[] = {"dhh", "aci", "cdh"};
    join_def(strings,'|',3); //<- need to send the length of the char* array

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```